# Can't turn off Files On-Demand in OneDrive

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I bought a new PC and installed Windows 10. I have almost 1TB of files on OneDrive, and I want it all to be available offline. However, when I try to deactivate the "Save space and download files as you use them" option under "Settings", it just doesn't turn off.

I click the checkbox, and then there is a dialog box:

"Disable Files On-Demand

All OneDrive files and folders will download to this PC

OK/Cancel"

I click OK, and then... The checkbox is still checked! So there seems to be no way to uncheck it. This is very weird behavior, might be a bug.

Any ideas how to turn off Files On-Demand considering the checkbox doesn't want to be unchecked? Maybe a registry edit or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open settings, "About" tab, check the "Get OneDrive Insider preview updates" checkbox, wait 10 mins, try unchecking "File-on-demand" again

Comment: This worked immediately!  Thanks.

Comment: Yay, that worked! I guess this is a bug that they fixed in the newer version. I hope the preview build is as stable and reliable as the release build, though...

Comment: I concur that this is a bug introduced quite recently. I've got four OneDrive accounts synchronising and can't turn off files on-demand via the checkbox on any of them

Comment: Confirmed that it's fixed in the insiders release of OneDrive

Answer (score 5):

I have selected "Always keep on this device" from the location shown (main OneDrive icon, see screenshot), and it seems to be working as if the Files on Demand checkbox was UNSELECTED although it stays checked (the behavior is there, just not unchecked in settings).  As I sync other folders, they now download as I add them.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. I already tried everything what I could find:

- reset OneDrive
- un- and re-install OneDrive
- un- and re-link my account
- force files on demand in regedit
- sfc /scannow
- re-installed Windows without any third-party apps

I think it has something to do with this:
https://hothardware.com/news/windows-10-may-2020-update-broken-onedrive-files

Comment: hi James, thanks for trying to help but please avoid "me-too" responses and hunches about what the cause might be. These are not suitable as answers on Super User. In any case this question already has an accepted answer. Please keep https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers in mind when preparing answers.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the May 2020 (2004) Windows 10 update as this occurs on all builds. AFAIK OneDrive updates itself independently of Windows 10. It was introduced in OneDrive v20.084.0426.0007 but fixed in v20.124.0621.0006 which in the insider ring, i.e. not production

Answer (score 0):

I right clicked the onedrive folder and checked always keep files on this device.  It's now downloading but I don't know if it will continue to sink right after then.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too, but the checkbox is still checked, and I feel like I might have to do that again if I modify the files on another device. I just want to guarantee that all the files are always available offline (for cases where, well, I'm offline!) and this should totally be possible, and indeed was the case in my old PC, but for some reason that option doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

I try to disable/turn off OneDrive Files On-Demand from OneDrive Settings. The status marks disappear and OneDrive start to download all files to my computer.

[image]

If the Files On-Demand option is still checked, You try to unlink the PC and log out OneDrive. Then try to log in OneDrive back. Check if you can uncheck the option.

If the issue persists, you can try to reset OneDrive according to [Reset OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c). Please back up files if necessary.

According to the official article [Save disk space with OneDrive Files On-Demand for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e), Files On-Demand might not be compatible with some third-party antivirus solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and can confirm that this is fixed in the latest production build 20.114.0607.0001

The link to this version can be found on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/onedrive-release-notes-845dcf18-f921-435e-bf28-4e24b95e5fc0#ID0EACAAA-supTabControlContent-1:%7E:text=Current%20and%20pre%2Drelease%20versions).

Direct download link [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=860984).